# Gulp Server throw err

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I am trying to run gulp serve to start my live load that was previously working. After I updated node and npm I am getting the following:

```
$ gulp serve
module.js:515
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'internal/util/types'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:513:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:463:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:556:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:31:26
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Development\Template\studio_billing\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:11:
1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:612:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:623:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:531:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:494:12)
```

Here is my gulpfile:

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var reload      = browserSync.reload;

// Save a reference to the `reload` method

// Watch scss AND html files, doing different things with each.
gulp.task('serve', function () {

    // Serve files from the root of this project
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./"
        }
    });

    gulp.watch("*.html").on("change", browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch("assets/css/*.css").on("change", browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch("assets/js/*.js").on("change", browserSync.reload);
});
```

I am running Node 8.8.1 and NPM 5.2.0. I am honestly just looking for something to watch changes to my files I am working on and refresh the browser. This solution use to work great but with updating NODE and NPM it seems to have broken it. Any type of solution would be awesome!

Everything use to work just fine before the update. I had updated NPM and Node because of a Laravel project in a different folder.

Comment: See if it helps: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19032

Comment: @NickN were you able to resolve this problem?